# iOS - scrollViewDidEndDecelerating runs for both scrollView and collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scrollview, collectionview

I have a VC that contains a `collectionView` and a `scrollView`. I put this code to change current page of `pageController` by scrolling in scrollView :

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    self.pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

It works nice for `scrollView` but the problem is when i even scroll in `collectionView` it declares and causes unwanted changing in `pageController`!

What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answers posted above, You can make use of the tag property of the view.

Just assign a tag (Int) to your scrollview either in xib or via code.

```
yourScrollView.tag = 10
```

And in the scrollview delegate method check for this tag:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.tag == 10 { 
      ///Your scrollview was scrolled
    } else {
      // Collection view was scrolled
    }

}
```

Comment: @Dr.Arash Good to know. Feel free to upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if scrollView == yourScrollView{
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    self.pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

check if the instance running the method is actually your scrollView

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand bit detail about `UICollectionView`. The `UICollectionView` is subclassed from `UIScrollView`. That's why its getting called for both the scrolling (Scrolling collection view and scrolling scroll view). You can do like this to differentiate what type of scrolling it is,

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == "Your scrollView outlet name" { // Scroll view
        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        self.pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    } else {
      // Collection view
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Fine. Happy coding.

Comment: ;))) u too @Karthick

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `scrollView` inside the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` if it is your scroll view or your collection view.
Just add an `if scrollView == myScrollView` before doing the 2 lines of code you have.

Your code shoudl look like this

func

```
scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == myScrollView {
        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        self.pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
}
```