# How to add tag in UICollectionView's ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController that have multiple UICollectionView, the problem is my `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` was getting triggered when I scroll on any of my UICollectionView,

What I want is call a function on `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` by only one of my UICollectionView,

I see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455871/6800631) where they comparing the `ScrollView` to the scrollView parameter given by `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` like adding a tag on their scrollView and check if `scrollView.tag == myScrollView.tag`, the issue is I can't add a tag in the scrollView inside of my UICollectionView.

This is my sample code on `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to make it clearer

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("hello")
}
```

It also applied to the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` function

Comment: @matt but how can I identify the UICollectionView that will going to use the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`?

Comment: @matt yes, but that's the scrollView of all UICollectionView inside my UIViewcontroller, I mean any UICollectionView have that scrollView, how can I identify where UICollectionView will I use?

Comment: @matt UICollectionViews are scrollable, when I scroll on any UICollectionView, they're all calling the same function inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, example, I have 2 UICollectionViews, I want to call the code inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` but not call it on another UICollectionView when it scrolls

Comment: I see, sorry I get confused, so that scrollView was the `UICollectionView`, now i get it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection view *is* a scroll view, and a collection view delegate is a scroll view delegate. So just implement `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and the `scrollView` that arrives into the call will be the collection view that is being scrolled.

You can identify *which* collection view it is either by a tag or by an outlet, or you can give the collection view some other sort of identifying feature (I like to give my views names).